# Convert a formula to a quadratic formula.

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

I've just started to learn Quantum annealing and I have found that I have to convert my problem into its quadratic form. I have to use something named QUBO.

To start with, I have tried to find a solution for a lineal regression problem (from machine learning).

This is the cost function for this algorithm:

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1)=\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=0}^m(h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)^2$$

where

$$h_\theta(x_i)=\theta_0+\theta_1x_i$$

In a linear regression problem you have a set of input values, $x_i$, and their corresponding outputs, $y_i$. For example, you have a set of houses' size, $x_i$, and their prices, $y_i$.

To goal of a linear regression problem is to find a formula, $h_\theta(x_i)$, that a produces the value of $y_i$ when you input it the value of $x_i$.

In the cost function, I square the difference between the guessed value, $h_\theta(x_i)$, minus the real value $y_i$.

Do you know if I can convert the cost function into a quadratic formula?

By the way, I'm not asking about how to minimize $J(\theta_0,\theta_1)$, **I'm asking about how to convert into its quadratic form**.

Comment: to minimize J, take partial derivatives w.r.t. \theta_0 and 1, set both equal to 0 and solve the linear equations (if that is what you're trying to do)

Comment: @S.Klumpers By the way, I'm not asking about how to minimize $J(\theta_0,\theta_1)$, **I'm asking about how to convert into its quadratic form**.

Comment: @VansFannel do you mean how to transform this into something that looks like $\vec{z}^T\matrix{A}\vec{w}$?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Yes, I mean that. Thanks.